# maximize load but don't bring it to a crawl

Tags: php, unix, shell, cpu

I have a shell script that runs very cpu intensive programs. FFMPEG,ffmpeg2theora,etc. and I want to be able to run them but not choke the server. Is there something I can do to make sure the running programs are running as fast as possible but not hurting the server?

Like a priority system...if something else comes along that needs it the other programs drop in priority aka cpu usage. I know there is "nice" but with the above programs are not working with it.

I played with cpulimit but that makes me say it can't go higher than that even though there may be a light load and it could handle more.

Any existing unix tools or ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> I know there is "nice" but with the above programs are not working with it.

Can you define "not working"?  Setting a nice value of 20 *should* allow the program to use as much CPU time as possible, yielding to anything of a higher priority that needs the CPU.

What nice *doesn't* do is throttle I/O.  Video conversion is kind of I/O dependent. For that, there's [ionice](http://friedcpu.wordpress.com/2007/07/17/why-arent-you-using-ionice-yet/), but that comes with some caveats.

Comment: "not working" means cpu is at 99-100% and can't browse a webpage on the server.

Comment: Have you checked the process' nice level in `ps`?  Try viewing all processes using `top`, also check `iostat`.  You might be dealing with an I/O issue here, not a CPU use issue.  Also, make sure that you're nice-ing the right way.  Higher numbers mean lower priority, lower (negative) numbers mean higher priority.